# Как обратиться к сайту по IP-адресу из браузера

Tags: ip, dns

Осуществляю переезд сайта на новый сервер.

Скопировал сайт на новый сервер. Изменил А-записи в управлении доменом.

Хочу не дожидаясь обновления на DNS серверах проверить, что на новом сервере сайт работает как положено. Как из браузера обратиться к сайту явно указав, с какого сервера получать данные, учитывая что на серверах множество сайтов?

Answer (score 0):

В запросе должен присутствовать HTTP-заголовок `Host`.
Поэтому придётся обращаться таки по домену.

А вот в какой IP этот домен отрезольвится можно указать в /etc/hosts файле.

В windows этот файл лежит в `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Answer (score 0):

Если сайт установлен в нужный каталог , вы можете просто в бить адрес в строке браузера и он будет доступен. Ожидать обновление DNS нужно , если Вы привязали домен к Вашему сайту, а если сайтов много тогда в конфиге веб -сервера установить его приоритетным